# Bash line comment continuation

Tags: bash, shell, comments

I have seen some bash/shell comments use the notation

```
#  Some comment block that starts on line 1, but then
#+ continues on line 2 with this silly plus sign.

#  And this is another comment line that is not related to the ones above
```

Does the "#+" help with any kind of parser (like how Doxygen-style comments are used to auto-generate documentation)?

Is this a common practice? I understand that it doesn't hurt anything to include/exclude it, as far as the actual script execution goes, but I'm curious if there are advantages to adopting this style of commenting.

Comment: I've seen this a lot too and I've always wondered the reason for it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html), it looks like this is one of several [comment headers](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#COMMENTH) one can use to improve *clarity and legibility* in scripts. This tidbit is presented in the "Assorted Tips" section of the guide:

> Use special-purpose comment headers to increase clarity and legibility in scripts.

Here are several of the ones they list in the example block from the guide:

```
## Caution.
rm -rf *.zzy   ##  The "-rf" options to "rm" are very dangerous,
               ##+ especially with wild cards.

#+ Line continuation.
#  This is line 1
#+ of a multi-line comment,
#+ and this is the final line.

#* Note.

#o List item.

#> Another point of view.
while [ "$var1" != "end" ]    #> while test "$var1" != "end"
```

Apparently some people find these little bits helpful, but I personally don't see much benefit in doing it.

Comment: Excellent link to ABS, thank you. So apparently, it's less of a documentation-generation notation, and more of a simple readability convention.

Comment: Or anti-readability, depending on the faste. I'd rather use paragraphs than those funky `+`.